# How to limit access from pivot table? Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot, relationships

I have tables:

user

- id
- name

companies

- id
- name

company_user

- company_id
- user_id

Tables has *Many To Many* relationships.

As it complicated relationship for me, I can't find way how to make this limit, when user can see companies that was created by this user. (probably not well experienced)

Now I have this, but user can see any company

*CompanyController:*

```
public function show($company_id)
{
    $company = Company::where('id', $company_id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('company.settings', compact('company'));
}
```

So tip me please how to make user can see only companies created by this user.

Comment: Do you have a [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship defined on the `User` model?

Comment: public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'company_user');
    }

Comment: also .   public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'company_user');
    }

Comment: My mistake, you need it on the `Company` model for this, do you have it as well? Also what do you mean "by this user"? Currenlty logged in user?

Comment: Actually relationships works, it's not the issue in my case

Comment: Yes currently logged user

Comment: Answered it below. I asked for the relationship because it's needed (or at least to do it in idiomatic Laravel way) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public function show($company_id)
{
    $company = auth()->user()->companies()->findOrFail($company_id);
    return view('company.settings', compact('company'));
}
```

It will scope the company to the currently logged in user (through the many-to-many relationship on the `User` model). If none is found, it will return 404.

Answer (score 0):

Since it many to many relation, you can map one company to many users, also map one user to many companies. Check if you have not mistakenly assign the company to many user

Also the above code can be written the way

```
public function show($company_id)
{
    $company = Company::findOrFail($company_id);

    return view('company.settings', compact('company'));
}
```

Comment: In my case users can create many companies, and they can add users to the company, so one company can have many users, and users can have many companies. Thats why I have relationship belongsToMay() for users and same for the company. I'm using the pivot table for this